# Edit a file with $VISUAL, wait for it to be saved before using it

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script to keep my personal notes accessible through the command line. The script uses [`gum write`](https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum#write) for editing the note, and this works great for short snippets, but it isn't ideal for writing anything longer than a paragraph or so.

I want to allow the user to edit the file in their preferred editor and wait for them to finish editing it before continuing the rest of the script, alike to functionality in Git. Specifically, running `git commit` without specifying a commit message will open an editor and wait with the message "Waiting for your editor to close the file..."

I've tried to implement this with the following shell script...

```
printf "Creating a new note..."
# Ask the user to edit the note
$VISUAL note.txt
# Process the note somehow...
mv note.txt ~/my-notes-folder/
```

...but this snippet doesn't work as I expected. I've tried to use the $VISUAL and $EDITOR variables, but I have $VISUAL set to `code` (as in Visual Studio Code). I expected the command to wait until I'm finished or closed the file like Git does, but it simply opens the file and moves it without waiting.

Comment: if you want to use vscode as a commit message editor: use `code --wait`

Comment: Then do it with i.e. `VISUAL=nano`.

Comment: But then the onus should be on the user to correctly set `VISUAL='code --wait'`

Comment: Using code --wait instead of code was my issue! Thanks guys! I'm not sure how Stack Overflow works, should this question be marked as invalid? How can I mark a comment as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple loop to check for the file to change.

```
md5=$(md5sum note.txt)
$VISUAL note.txt
while true; do
    sleep 5
    if [[ "$(md5sum note.txt)" != "$md5" ]]; then
        break
    fi
    echo "$0: waiting for you to save a new version of note.txt ..." >&2
done
```

This is obviously still brittle; what if the user makes extensive edits and saves while still editing? But for simple tasks this is probably good enough.